# What name and formula describes the curve of where a plane intersects a cylinder?

Tags: geometry, plane-geometry, intersection-theory, cylindrical-coordinates

Given a cylinder of infinite height and a plane that intersects the cylinder where the plane may be inclined at an arbitrary angle relative to the plane whose intersection produces a perfect circle, what is the class of curves one can produce and what is their formula?

I'm thinking that since you get a circle at zero degrees it is likely the set of curves are all ellipses, but I'm not sure how to demonstrate that.  If it they are ellipses, how do you compute the foci and formulas as a function of the angle?

Comment: Intuitively I'd say the same, but you at least need to exclude the case where the plane is parallel to the axis of the cylinder. In this particular case, the intersection is either empty, one line or two parallel lines. Also for these kind of things, putting everything into equations is usually the best way to ensure you don't forget the degenerate cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are ellipses. You build two  spheres tangent to the plane inside the cylinder. Then you consider the point of intersection of the sphere with the plane as foci $F_1$ and $F_2$ of the ellipse, then you take an arbitrary point $P$ on the intersection and show that the sum of $PF_1+PF_2$ is a constant, more exactly is the distance between the two circumferences where the spheres are tangent to the cylinder.
[image]

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Forget about the locus definition of ellipses. In the first place an *ellipse* is the image of a circle under parallel projection, or  the curve you are talking about in your question, or the curve obtained by linearly scaling a circle in one of two plane directions.

It so happens that ellipses have some interesting geometric properties, e.g., this thing about foci, reflections of rays through the foci at the boundary, etcetera.

Answer (score 0):

There are two more possibilities of non-empty intersection, apart from an ellipse:

1. The plane is tangent to the cylinder, intersecting it at an infinite straight line.
2. The plane is a tangent plane pushed a little bit inside the cylinder, so the intersection is a pair of parallel lines.

An alternative, slightly more general argument and more algebraic to that given above by Raffaele is as follows.

Assume the cylinder is given by $x^2+y^2=k^2$. Let $P$ be a plane with a normal vector $u$. We may rotate the plane while keeping the $z$-axis fixed, so that we may assume that $u=(\alpha,0,\beta)$ and that $\alpha^2+\beta^2=1$, so that the equation of the plane is
$$\alpha x+\beta z=d$$
for some $d$. Let's translate our intersection to the subspace perpendicular to $u$, denoted $u^\perp$. In that subspace, the vectors $w_1=(0,1,0)$ and $w_2=(-\beta,0,\alpha)$ are an orthonormal basis.
If $\beta=0$, then our plane $P$ is perpendicular to $(1,0,0)$, and in this case the intersection is either empty, one line or two parallel lines. Assume henceforth that $\beta\neq 0$.
If $(x,y,z)$ is in the plane $P$, then its translation to $u^\perp$ can be expressed in terms of the basis $w_1,w_2$ by:
$$(x-d\alpha,y,z-d\beta)=yw_1+\frac{d\alpha-x}{\beta}w_2$$
This equation holds because $\alpha x+\beta z=d$ and also because $\alpha^2+\beta^2=1$.
Put $u=y$ and $v=\frac{d\alpha-x}{\beta}$. In the coordinates $u,v$, every point in our translated intersection satisfies the equation
$$u^2+(d\alpha-\beta v)^2=k^2$$
because this is exactly the equation $y^2+x^2=k^2$ for a point lying in the plane $P$. Since $\beta\neq 0$, the affine map:
$$T(uw_1+vw_2)=uw_1-(d\alpha-\beta v)w_2$$
is non-singular, and since $w_1,w_2$ are an orthonormal basis,  our set is just the image of the circle $u^2+v^2=k^2$ under the inverse affine map $T^{-1}$, so it is an ellipse.

An analogous argument can be applied to the analysis of conic sections. The resulting quadratic is a bit more complicated, allowing, in addition to ellipses, also parabolas, hyperbolas and single points to appear as conic sections.